# Reliable way to get path to py file of a module

Tags: python, cross-platform, relative-path, file-location

I'm trying to figure out the best way to reliably discover at runtime the location on the file system of the `py` file for a given module.  I need to do this because I plan to externalize some configuration data about some methods (in this case, schemas to be used for validation of responses from service calls for which interfaces are defined in a module) for cleanliness and ease of maintenance.

An simplified illusutration of the system:

```
package
|
|-service.py
|
|-call1.scm
|
|-call2.scm
```

service.py (`_call()` is a method on the base class, though that's irrelevant to the question)

```
class FooServ(AbstractService):
    def call1(*args):
        result = self._call('/relative/uri/call1', *args)
        # additional call specific processing
        return result
    def call2(*args):
        result = self._call('/relative/uri/call2', *args)
        # additional call specific processing
        return result
```

call1.scm and call2.scm define the response schemas (in the current case, using the draft JSON schema format, though again, irrelevant to the question)

In another place in the codebase, when the service calls are actually made, I want to be able to detect the location of `service.py` so that I can traverse the file structure and find the scm files.  At least on my system, I think that this will work:

```
# I realize this is contrived here, but in my code, the method is accessed this way
method = FooServ().call1
module_path = sys.modules[method.__self__.__class__.__module__].__file__
schema_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(module_path), method.__name__ + '.scm')
```

However, I wanted to make sure this would be safe on all platforms and installation configurations, and I came across [this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/) while doing research, which made me concerned that trying to do this this way will not work reliably.  Will this work universally, or is the fact that `__file__` on a module object returns the location of the `pyc` file, which could be in some location other than along side the `py` file, going to make this solution ineffective?  If it will make it ineffective, what, if anything, can I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/) you link, it says:

> In Python 3, when you import a module, its __file__ attribute points to its source py file (in Python 2, it points to the pyc file).

So in Python 3 you're fine because `__file__` will always point to the `.py` file. In Python 2 it might point to the `.pyc` file, but that `.pyc` will only ever be in the same directory as the `.py` file for Python 2.

---

Okay, I think you're referring to this bit:

> Because these distributions cannot share pyc files, elaborate mechanisms have been developed to put the resulting pyc files in non-shared locations while the source code is still shared. Examples include the symlink-based Debian regimes python-support [8] and python-central [9]. These approaches make for much more complicated, fragile, inscrutable, and fragmented policies for delivering Python applications to a wide range of users.

I believe those mechanisms are applied only to Python modules that are packaged by the distribution. I don't *think* they should affect modules installed manually outside of the distribution's packaging system. It would be the responsibility of whoever was packaging your module for that distribution to make sure that the module isn't broken by the mechanism.

Comment: I am on Python 2.7.  I was more concerned by the large chunk of text talking about the haphazard and inconsistent ways in which various interpreters and OS configurations handle pyc file generation.

Comment: To your edit: that would make sense.  I think I'll try to track down a Mac and a couple other platforms to see what goes on there, but I feel more confident that things should work out ok now.  Thanks.

Comment: I confirmed this is the case for all platforms that matter to me, so I think I'm good.  Thanks again.